# How to get the section and subsections into each title bar in a slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer

This is something I've done in the past, but I cannot find it anywhere! Really sorry as I think it's probably very basic but I just want the section and subsection (or one or the other, I want at least one but currently I have none!) in the title or navigation bar on each slide to aid some context.

Comment: Do you want this for just one slide or every slide? Do you want sub-/section names or numbers?

Comment: Excellent questions. Every slice and names

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the sub-/section names to the frame title using the `\patchcmd` command from `etoolbox`. The following command

```
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsection. \insertsubsection. \insertframetitle}{}{}
```

adds the section and subsection names before inserting the frame title.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\insertsection. \insertsubsection. \insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Sub 1.1}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
  some content
\end{frame}

\section{Sec 2}
\subsection{Sub 2.1}
\frame{\frametitle{{}} no frame title}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]